# Fluid 960 Grid jQuery slideToggle

Tags: jquery, css, laravel, slidetoggle, 960.gs

I am using Fluid 960 Grid for my site and I am using jQuery (the latest).

I want to slideToggle a div which is a child div of a div called `serviceitem1`. Here is my code:

```
div id="serviceitem1"> strong> Service One /strong>
    div class="services">
        ksdjfslkdjfs
    /div>
/div>

$('#serviceitem1').click(function(eve){
    $(this).children().slideToggle('slow'); 
});
```

The toggling works, however when I click to slide down, the resulting div which is exposed slowly jumps and covers the first div element which I had clicked and the entire frame of the site appears to jump slightly.

I have tried looking at it in IE10, Firefox 19 and the latest Chrome and I get the same result. I am using Windows 8 Pro.

Does this make sense to anyone? Also I am using Laravel 3.2.11 as my framework. Would Blade be causing any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guyz,

I chose to deal with this the easy way by using id's on the services div and removing it completely as a child of the upper div named serviceitem1. That way I was able to have the animation and not have this jumping issue. But if anyone does come up with an answer I would appreciate it if they would share the answer.

Eagletrophy